# How to save uint64_t bytes to file on C?

Tags: c, unix

How to save uint64_t bites to file on plain C?

As i suppose output file will be 8 bytes length?

Comment: 8 bytes? So you want a binary file not a text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT.** Since my compiler does not have `uint64_t` I have shown two ways to save a 64-bit value to file, by using `unsigned long long`. The first example writes it in (hex) text format, the second in binary.

Note that `unsigned long long` may be more than 64 bits on some systems.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    FILE *fout;
    unsigned long long my64 = 0x1234567887654321;

    // store as text
    fout = fopen("myfile.txt", "wt");
    fprintf(fout, "%llX\n", my64);
    fclose(fout);    

    // store as bytes
    fout = fopen("myfile.bin", "wb");
    fwrite(&my64, sizeof(my64), 1, fout);
    fclose(fout);    

    return 0;
}
```

Content of myfile.txt (hex dump)

```
31 32 33 34  35 36 37 38  38 37 36 35  34 33 32 31  1234567887654321
0D 0A                                               ..
```

Content of myfile.bin (hex dump) (little-endian)

```
21 43 65 87  78 56 34 12                            !Ce‡xV4.
```

Comment: That depends on uint64_t be identical to unsigned long long. Why not use PRIu64 from inttypes.h?

Comment: Well, whoever told you should be blamed for not knowing the standard. And the compiler/toolchain for not providing headers accordingly (unless that would be a freestanding environment, of course - but that would also not include stdio necessarily).

Comment: No I won't. Just another good reason not to use their products. Luckily there's enough (and often much better) tools from other vendors - and - of course OSS. However, I wonder how a company can actually "tell" you something.

Comment: Sorry, I read your comments as if "Microsoft told you not to use ...", Therefore I wondered. For the standard: Well it has added stdint.h for a reason. And that was to provide fixed size ints for certain applications (mostly embedded, but also file-formats, etc. Not sure (and don't mind)  what the OP wants it for. And for those it also defined inttypes.h so you do not have to break abstraction for printing/scanning. No idea what tool you're using, but it is not C99+ standard then. From your comments I suppose it might be VC (which is not C99 conforming).

Comment: For a quote: I actually just refer to the standard providing stdint.h (n1570, 7.20, inttiypes.h is 7.8) types. So, if you (or the other poster) now insist the standard disallows its use, it's up to you to provide a reference, not me actually.

Comment: Yeah. But a non-conforming tolchain is a bad reference for a standard.

Comment: Well, `%llu` _is_ cetainly the right for `unsigned long long`. But is is not for `uint64_t`, any coincidence is just by chance (actually implementation/architecture). The correct one would be `PRIu64` (or PRIx64 for hex). You do not put the cart before the horse.

Comment: Well, you did all of his job; many ppl here asking such simple questions like getting their work done by so else;-). I have no problem with the code, it's just the format. (Well, it strictly does not refer to the actual question, but who cares:-)

Comment: Welcome! Sorry if I appear to be a bit nit-picky sometimes. Tthat might result from me not being a native English-speaker. So I try to express as precise as possible but lack snappy phrases sometimes. Thich might sound like pedantry for native speakers sometimes. However, not sorry for what I actually meant (hope we do agree now:-).

Answer (score 2):

`fwrite(&sixty_four_bit_var, 8, 1, file_pointer)`

Comment: 8... or `sizeof(sixty_four_bit_var)`

Comment: Yep. But since the size is specified explicitly, I prefer to make the things clear specific to the question.

Comment: OP didn't say he wanted 8, he asked if that would be the size.

Comment: "As i suppose output file will be 8 bytes length?" I am not sure about the meaning of it. The other question was "how to save"

Comment: @Eregrith: While I agree in general, uint64_t is guaranteed to have 64 bits (8 octets(sic!)), but `sizeof(uint64_t) == 8` is NOT.

Comment: @Olaf Just curious, have you met any architectures with `sizeof(uint64_t) != 8` ?

Comment: @Olaf: Please cite something in regard of sizeof(uint64_t) not guaranteed to be 8.

Comment: Not sure (didn't use sizeof back then), but maybe: a 24 bit DSP. Also: why become implementation-dependent without urgent need?

Comment: @Olaf I'm pretty sure `sizeof(uint64_t)` will **always** be equal to the size of an `uint64_t`, so whenever you write one, you can use that `sizeof` ... Eugene: If it's the file length that is fixed then I'd suggest a macro, at least ;)

Comment: @simon: Sizeof(char) ide defined by the standard to be 1. But: CHAR_BIT is not necessarly 8. Note that a "byte" is NOT defined 8 bits. There were machines with e.g. 9 bit bytes. And sizeof is multiples of sizeof(char). Just check the standard yourself, you'll find it.

Comment: @Eregrith: So far, but sizeof(uint64_t) * CHAR_BIT is not necessarily 64!

Comment: Guys, I agree that magic numbers is a bad practice in general. But I think it is not related to the question, so I tried to simplify the answer as much as possible.

Comment: Eugene: There's still the endianess-issue plus the variable need not necessarily start from offest 0. Impropable - acknowledged - but possible. And as there is no actual need, why not just avoid all that and serialize it the easy way properly?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend fprintf it as String. Easier to verify (cat or open in text editor) and no hazzle with endianess. Check `inttypes.h` for the proper format specifier (PRIu64).

Read back with fscanf, using SCNu64 as format specifier.

That will also work if the data type is not aligned to the first position. Whil impropable for uint64_t, consider a char of 1 octet, but not starting from offset 0 for some reason (big endian CPU with no 8 bit load/store e.g.). This would be allowed by the standard.

However, if you realy want to get 8-bit values, use the following:

```
uint64_t value = input_value;
for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++ ) {
    fputc(value & 0xFF), filep);
    value >>= 8;
}
```

That will store the value in little-endian format. Note that this is not guaranteed to work for signed due to the right-shift (but it will *very* likely).

For more complex structures, you might use a proper format like JSON with a library.

Comment: What the difference by storing as text or as bytes?

Comment: I'm going to store utf8 like bytes.

Comment: @AntonMedvedev: I think I already explaint that. However, added another issue. Direct write of a scaler type is actually implementation dependent, /De)Serialization through printf/scanf is not.

Comment: @AntonMedvedev: UTF-8 is not bytes! Codes 0..127 (ASCII-page) a a single octet, higher codes are stored as groups of octets (run-length encoding). Note also, that the size of a "byte" is **not** fixed. That's why I prefer the term "octet" (from greek "octa"-eight). You might know the file-type "application/octet-stream" already.