# C++. Struct padding / alignment on different platforms and atomatic check of layout compatibility

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, embedded, padding

I have embedded device connected to PC
and some big struct S with many fields and arrays of custom defined type FixedPoint_t.
FixedPoint_t is a templated POD class with exactly one data member that vary in size from char to long depending on template params. Anyway it passes `static_assert((std::is_pod<FixedPoint_t<0,8,8> >::value == true),"");`

It will be good if this big struct has compatible underlaying memory representation on both embedded system and controlling PC. This allows significant simplification of communication protocol to commands like "set word/byte with offset N to value V". Assume endianess is the same on both platforms.

I see 3 solutions here:

1. Use something like #pragma packed on both sides.
   BUT i got warning when i put **attribute**((**packed**)) to struct S declaration
   ***warning: ignoring packed attribute because of unpacked non-POD field.***
   This is because FixedPoint_t is not declared as **packed**.
   I don't want declare it as packed because this type is widely used in whole program and packing can lead to performance drop.
2. Make correct struct serialization. This is not acceptable because of code bloat, additional RAM usege...Protocol will be more complicated because i need random access to the struct. Now I think this is not an option.
3. Control padding manually. I can add some field, reorder others...Just to acheive no padding on both platforms. This will satisfy me at the moment. But i need good way to write a test that shows me is padding is there or not. 
   I can compare sum of sizeof() each field to sizeof(struct).
   I can compare offsetof() each struct field on both platforms.
   Both variants are ugly enough...

What do you recommend? Especially i am interested in manual padding controling and automaic padding detection in tests.

**EDIT:** Is it sufficient to compare sizeof(big struct) on two platforms to detect layout compatibility(assume endianess is equal)?? I think size should not match if padding will be different.

**EDIT2:**

```
//this struct should have padding on 32bit machine
//and has no padding on 8bit
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t f8;
    uint32_t f32;
    uint8_t arr[5];
} serialize_me_t;

//count of members in struct
#define SERTABLE_LEN    3 

//one table entry for each serialize_me_t data member
static const struct {
    size_t width;
    size_t offset;
//    size_t cnt;  //why we need cnt?
} ser_des_table[SERTABLE_LEN] =
    {
        { sizeof(serialize_me_t::f8), offsetof(serialize_me_t, f8)},
        { sizeof(serialize_me_t::f32), offsetof(serialize_me_t, f32)},
        { sizeof(serialize_me_t::arr), offsetof(serialize_me_t, arr)},
    };

void serialize(void* serialize_me_ptr, char* buf)
{
    const char* struct_ptr = (const char*)serialize_me_ptr;
    for(int i=0; i<SERTABLE_LEN; I++)
    {   
        struct_ptr += ser_des_table[i].offset;
        memcpy(buf, struct_ptr, ser_des_table[i].width );        
        buf += ser_des_table[i].width;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not edit/expand yourr question. This is no discussion forum. If there is another issue ask a new question. But first, try yourself and do some research on aspects of the answers you got. (memcpy is **not** the proper way to serialize. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508725/how-to-save-uint64-t-bytes-to-file-on-c/30508873#30508873) for an example I provided in another answer just to get the idea of proper serialization. My approach does not care about padding. Also note that `memcpy` with its setup actually might take longer than shifting (which is highly optimizable).

Comment: Seems to be this is really great example of serialization and protocol C++ implementations. http://youtu.be/wbZdZKpUVeg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend to use option 2:

- You are save for future changes (new PCD/ABI, compiler, platform, etc.)
- Code-bloat can be kept to a minimum if well thought. There is just one function needed per direction.
- You can create the required tables/code (semi-)automatically (I use Python for such). This way both sides will stay in sync.
- You definitively should add a CRC to the data anyway. As you likely do not want to calculate this in the rx/tx-interrupt, you'll have to provide an array anyway.
- Using a struct directly will soon become a maintenance nightmare. Even worse if someone else has to track this code.
- Protocols, etc. tend to be reused. If it is a platform with different endianess, the other approach goes bang.

To create the data-structs and ser/des tables, you can use `offsetof` to get the offset of each type in the struct. If that table is made an include-file, it can be used on both sides. You can even create the struct and table e.g. by a Python script. Adding that to the build-process ensures it is always up-to-date and you avoid additional typeing.

For instance (in C, just to get idea):

```
// protocol.inc

typedef struct {
    uint32_t i;
    uint 16_t s[5];
    uint32_t j;
} ProtocolType;

static const struct {
    size_t width;
    size_t offset;
    size_t cnt;
} ser_des_table[] = {
    { sizeof(ProtocolType.i), offsetof(ProtocolType.i), 1 },
    { sizeof(ProtocolType.s[0]), offsetof(ProtocolType.s), 5 },
    ...
};
```

If not created automatically, I'd use macros to generate the data. Possibly by including the file twice: one to generate the struct definition and one for the table. This is possible by redefining the macros in-between.

You should care about the representation of signed integers and floats (*implementation defined*, floats are likely IEEE754 as proposed by the standard).

As an alternative to the `width` field, you can use an "type" code (e.g. a `char` which maps to an implementation-defined type. This way you can add custom types with same width, but different encoding (e.g. uint32_t and IEEE754-`float`). This will completely abstract the network protocol encoding from the physical machine (the best solution). Note noting hinders you from using common encodings which do not complicate code a single bit (literally).

Comment: I am sorry, can you provide more complete example of using ser_des_table please? I think don't get the whole idea yet...

Comment: I do not understand what you are missing. For each packet received/to transmit you just iterate throught he table and (de)serialize the packet data from a buffer to a struct.

Comment: Added code to my original question. Am i understood your idea? I only have a question about why we need cnt in table?

Comment: @sigmaN: `cnt` would be required for the 2nd field, as that is an array. Sorry, I really should have added that, too (done now, see edit). If you do not have arrays, you do not need that field, of course. If you want to save memory, you can also use smaller types than `size_t`, if you are sure the values will not be too large (a good idea might be to have `width` and `cnt` each have `uint16_t` or even `unsigned char` - see text for `width`)